# Error while indexing files

Tags: java, apache, indexing, lucene

```
package lia.meetlucene;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class Indexer {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length != 2) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Usage: java " + Indexer.class.getName()
        + " <index dir> <data dir>");
    }
    String indexDir = args[0];         //1
    String dataDir = args[1];          //2

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Indexer indexer = new Indexer(indexDir);
    int numIndexed;
    try {
      numIndexed = indexer.index(dataDir);
    } finally {
      indexer.close();
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Indexing " + numIndexed + " files took "
      + (end - start) + " milliseconds");
  }

  private IndexWriter writer;

  public Indexer(String indexDir) throws IOException {
    Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File(indexDir));
    writer = new IndexWriter(dir,            //3
                 new StandardAnalyzer(       //3
                     Version.LUCENE_30),//3
                 true,                       //3
                             IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED); //3
  }

  public void close() throws IOException {
    writer.close();                             //4
  }

  public int index(String dataDir)
    throws Exception {
try{
    File[] files = new File(dataDir).listFiles();

    for (File f: files) {                
    ************************************************        
         if(f.isDirectory())           // I added this if block which is causing error
        {
            index(dataDir);
        }
    ************************************************
       else if (!f.isDirectory() &&
          !f.isHidden() &&
          f.exists() &&
          f.canRead()
          ) {
        indexFile(f);
      }
    }
}
      catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return writer.numDocs();                     //5
  }


  protected Document getDocument(File f) throws Exception {
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new Field("contents", new FileReader(f)));      //7
    doc.add(new Field("filename", f.getName(),              //8
                Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));//8
    doc.add(new Field("fullpath", f.getCanonicalPath(),     //9
                Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));//9
    return doc;
  }

  private void indexFile(File f) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Indexing " + f.getCanonicalPath());
    Document doc = getDocument(f);
    writer.addDocument(doc);                              //10
  }
}
```

This is a program given in **Lucene** In *Action Book.* It is indexing only files in parent folder not in subfolders. So I added a if block to recursively find the files in subfolders. But after running this program it is creating write.lock file and it keep on creating index files even after closing the command prompt. What is the problem with the code?

I am new to `Lucene` and `Java`, previously I tried using apache commons io to find subfolders but I am getting package does not exist error ([package org.apache.commons.io does not exist error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673618/package-org-apache-commons-io-does-not-exist-error)).

Comment: Can you show us the error and the line caused that error?

Comment: Marked the line with *

Comment: @JUBA its not showing error it keeps on running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea it'll keep Running because you are passing the same path all the time. so you will not reach the `close()` method, that why the `write.lock` keep existing.

here you current code.

```
if(f.isDirectory())           
{
     index(dataDir); // dataDir is the orginal path
}
```

what you have to do is like this :

```
if(f.isDirectory())           
{
     index(f.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Comment: Thanks that really helped. One more question how come the indexing still continues even after I closed the command prompt?

Comment: No it is not, what happened is that `lucene` haven't a chance to unlock the Directory, `lucene` unlock the resources when you close the `IndexWriter` by calling `writer.close()`, and in your case the close method didn't called, so the `write.lock` file still exist.